# How can I determine permissions in a hierarchical organization?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, hierarchy

I’m trying to create performant logic for determining permissions within a hierarchical organization.

Employees are assigned to one or more units. Units are hierarchical with (theoretically) infinite depth (in reality it’s no more than 6 layers).

For example, employee `Jane` may be the `Supervisor` of the `Accounts Receivable` unit (a child of the `Accounting` unit), and also `Member` of the `Ethics Committee` (a child of `Committees`, which is itself a child of `Office of the CEO`).

As the `Supervisor` of `Accounts Receivable`, `Jane` should have permission to view personnel files of everyone else in `Accounts Receivable`, but not in the `Ethics Committee` since she’s just a `Member`. Similarly, regular employees of the `Accounts Receivable` unit should not be able to view one another’s profiles, though they’d all need permission to, say, view the accounting records of the company.

I imagine the database architecture for this will look something like:

```
| **employees** | **units**   | **positions** | **assignments** | **permissions** |
| ------------- | ----------- | ------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| id            | id          | id            | employee_id     | unit_id         |
| name          | name        | title         | unit_id         | is_management   |
|               | parent_path | is_management | position_id     | ability         |
```

With that in mind, how can I write a performant query to determine which permissions `Jane` has over `Sam`, an `Accountant` in `Accounts Receivable`, versus over `Bill`, a `Receptionist` in `Office of the CEO`?

The closest I have is something like:

```
create function permissions(actor employees, subject employees) returns setof permissions as $$
begin
  for unit_id in select unit_id from assignments where employee_id = subject.id loop
    select permissions.name
    from assignments
    left join units on (unit.id = assignments.unit_id)
    left join positions on (positions.id = assignments.position_id)
    left join permissions on (
      permissions.unit_id = units.id
      and permissions.is_management = positions.is_management
    )
    where assignments.user_id = actor.id
      and (units.parent_path = unit_id or units.parent_path @> unit_id)
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```