# Where do I put a complex permissions query for a user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add authorization logic to my application. I'm planning to use [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) but I still need to write the authorization logic itself, and I'm not sure where it should live: as an instance method on the User model, or a class method, or a scope, or perhaps on the Permission model?

The logic is a bit complex (per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360881/how-can-i-determine-permissions-in-a-hierarchical-organization)) as it involves nested joins with join conditions. Here it is in PostgreSQL. I imagine it's possible to convert it to ActiveRecord, perhaps with a bit of raw sql mixed in.

```
create function personnel.permissions_on_unit(
  actor_id integer,
  unit_id  integer
) returns text[] as $$

select array(
  select permission.ability
  from personnel.assignment
  inner join personnel.unit on (unit.id = assignment.unit_id)
  inner join personnel.position on (position.id = assignment.position_id)
  inner join personnel.permission on (
    permission.unit_id = assignment.unit_id
    and permission.access_level <= position.access_level
  )
  where assignment.user_id = $1
  and (
    unit.id = $2
    or unit.parent_path @> (
      select parent_path from personnel.unit where id = $2
    )
  )
);

$$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: Your problem is converting this postgresql logic into rails way OR where to keep this logic?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh primarily it's where to keep it. I provided the query for context, and would certainly welcome help with it, but I can poke at it for a while once I know where to put it.

Comment: I would use a [pundit scope](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right way, but I've created instance methods on my `User` model that query its associations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments

  def has_permission?(permission)
    permissions.pluck(:ability).include?(permission)
  end

  private
    def permissions
      @permissions ||= assignments
        .joins(:position, unit: :permissions)
        .where('permissions.access_level <= positions.access_level')
    end
end
```

I'd love any feedback on this approach. It's got my tests to pass so I hope I'm on the right track.